# Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:

Tags: java, maven, jhipster

when I followed the jhipster guide in github,I met this error.
I run mvnw.cmd,then I get this.
It looks like I can't pass the test.what should I do?
It may caused by maven-enforcer-plugin.
I had try to comment maven-enforcer-plugin in pom.xml,but It doesn't work.
thanks !!!!!!

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-versions) on project bug-tracker-j-hipster: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-versions) on project bug-tracker-j-hipster: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceMojo.execute (EnforceMojo.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
```

Comment: It seems there are multiple versions of the same library present and hence enforcer plugin is trying to tell you to fix it. Can you check which should be the right one for you and then you may either choose to exclude it from other library or mention the explicit version in dependecnyManagement.

Comment: You haven't pasted the enforcer errors above the exception, so we can't know which rule was broken. It could be dependency management or java version

Comment: yeah!I slove it by change my java version to 11.thanks a lot.